# Is it possible to ask R randomly pick two variables from a group of binary variables to calculate the proportion?

Tags: r

I have several binary variables in the dataset and I want to calculate the proportion of "1 1" of ALL the combinations of either two variables.For example the proportion of (a1=1 and a2=1). I can run the code with manually specifying the two variables each time, but I have more than 10 variables in my data, so there will be at least 45 combinations. Is there a way to ask R automatically pair up the variables to calculate for me?

```
structure(list(a1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                              .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               a2 = structure(c(1L,1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                              .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
               a3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L), 
                              .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
               a4 = structure(c(1L,2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                              .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor"), 
               a5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                              .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = 180:190, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @arkun I modified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function to get the `sample` of column names picking two, then subset the data, check whether both columns are equal to 1, get the `mean`

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
    nm1 <- sample(names(dat), 2, replace = FALSE)
    setNames(mean(dat[,nm1[1]]== 1 & dat[,nm1[2]] == 1), paste(nm1, collapse="_"))
   }

f1(df1)
# a3_a5 
#   0
```

---

If we want all the combinations

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
       combn(names(dat), 2, FUN = function(nm) {
              nm1 <- paste(nm, collapse="_")
              setNames(mean(dat[, nm[1]] ==1 & dat[, nm[2]] == 1), nm1)},
  simplify = FALSE) 
   }

f1(df1)
#[[1]]
#a1_a2 
#    0 

#[[2]]
#a1_a3 
#    0 

#[[3]]
#a1_a4 
#    0 

#[[4]]
#     a1_a5 
#0.09090909 

#[[5]]
#     a2_a3 
#0.09090909 

#[[6]]
#a2_a4 
#    0 

#[[7]]
#     a2_a5 
#0.09090909 

#[[8]]
#a3_a4 
#    0 

#[[9]]
#a3_a5 
#    0 

#[[10]]
#a4_a5 
#    0
```

Comment: It has an error says Error in dat[, x[1]] : incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't make my question clear. I would like to calculate the mean for all possible combinations. (this function did well in randomly picking either two to calculate the proportion each time though, but I need to run it repeatedly and not sure if I can get the results of all combinations)

Comment: @user12721567 ii though you want to `a way to ask R randomly pair up the variables to calculate for me`

Comment: Yes. And each time runing the function, there will be one result generated. Because it's randomly choosing the pair of variables, say if I have 10 variables, there can be 45 combinations. Even each time the combination generated is different, I will need to run the code for 45 times to get complete results I need, rt?

Comment: @user12721567 that is te reason I had `combn` earlier, but later changed because of the randomly pair up